# Tinymce Moxiemanager integration with dreamobjects cloud storage in php laravel

Tags: tinymce, dreamhost, moxiemanager

I am using [dreamobjects](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/categories/202115428-DreamObjects-Cloud-Storage) cloud storage for storing my user files. I am trying to use tinymce with moxiemanager plugin in frontend for forming messages which can contain images or documents present in the users files. I am capable of uploading files directly to the storage but my problem is how to integrate it with moxiemanager so that users can include one of their already uploaded files or even upload a new file directly from there.

I just want to know how to intercept the upload of files while using moxiemanager so that I can upload them using my code to dreamobjects and make some database entries. Basically, my problem is interception and then getting the file to reach my PHP helper/model code.

Comment: You need to setup your DreamObjects buckets so that each user has permission to upload and modify objects in it. Clarify your question adding what kind of access each user needs to have for the files. For example, does user A need not to see/modify objects uploaded by user B?

Comment: My problem is not uploading files to dreamobjects. I have that setup in my code. I just want to display files from dreamobjects to the users in the moxiemanager plugin and when users upload files how to configure moxiemanager to upload them to dreamobjects directly.

Comment: your statement is conflicting: `My problem is not uploading files to dreamobjects` but later you say you need help `how to configure moxiemanager to upload them to dreamobjects`. Try to be more clear and google `Moxiemanager S3` to get started.

Comment: @StefanoMaffulli I just wanted to know how to intercept the upload of files while using moxiemanager so that I can upload them using my code to dreamobjects and make some database entries. Basically, my problem is interception and then getting the file to reach my PHP helper/model code.

Comment: A google search shows the answer: http://www.moxiemanager.com/documentation/index.php/How_to_configure_for_AmazonS3

Comment: I don't have enterprise edition hence the amazon s3 plugin